# Does the UK still stamp their passport after refusal or denial in 2018?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, passport-stamps

I'm worried that if I get denied the UK visa my passport could be stamped and which is a big risk in case of any other time and any other country embassy like the USA or Canada.

Answer (score 8):

From the range of questions we keep on seeing here related to UK visa refusals, i can safely say that nobody mentions receiving a rejection stamp on their passport.

However, it does not matter. Stamp or no stamp, **you still have to declare** your previous refusals on the US and Canadian visa applications if asked.

> which is a big risk

Visa refusal will be recorded in the database regardless and if you don't declare it you risk a ban under deception. **A refusal is a very small risk compared to that.**

Comment: The US doesn't ask.  I don't know about Canada.